# $3$-manifolds with boundary having trivial $H_2$ and nontrivial relative $H_2$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am looking for examples of compact, connected and orientable $3$-manifolds $M$ with boundary such that $H_2(M; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ and $H_2(M,\partial M;\mathbb{Z}) \neq 0$. How big is this class? Is it finite, countable, uncountable?

It is interesting because if $M$ is a manifold having the above properties and $(\Sigma, \partial \Sigma) \subset (M, \partial M)$ is an embedded submanifold with boundary representing a nontrivial element of $H_2(M,\partial M;\mathbb{Z})$, then $\partial \Sigma$ represents a nontrivial element of $H_1(\partial M;\mathbb{Z})$. This follows from the fact that the map $H_2(M,\partial M;\mathbb{Z}) \to H_1(\partial M;\mathbb{Z})$ is injective is this case.

Comment: The entire set of homeomorphism classes of compact, connected, orientable 3-manifolds with boundary is countable; this is a consequence of [Moise's triangulation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)#Piecewise_linear_structures).

Comment: @MoisheKohan why is it empty?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Either you're misreading the question or I'm misreading it.  Why doesn't  for instance a solid torus satisfy the given hypotheses?  It deformation retracts to a circle, so $H_2$ of it is zero.  And the long exact sequence of a pair shows that $H_2$ of it rel boundary is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes, you are correct, I misread the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easy to come up with many such examples; for instance, consider a $3$-dimensional handlebody of genus at least $1$.  As Lee Mosher pointed out, there are only countable many compact 3-manifolds with boundary, so this shows that there are countably many examples.

Comment: I see that someone downvoted this.  I don't really care, but I assume it was due to Moishe Kohan's assertion in the comments that nothing satisfies the given conditions.  Let me assure you: I am correct (and he seems to agree since he deleted his comments).